# Programa Java Swing não abre janela fora do NetBeans, mas fica aberto nos processos

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

O meu problema é que eu fiz um programa em Java no NetBeans e na ele funciona normalmente, mas o problema é que, quando eu vou abrir a .jar fora da IDE, a janela não é aberta.

Aqui um código simples com o mesmo problema:

```
package bbb;
import javax.swing.*;

public class NewFrame extends JFrame{
    public NewFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }
    private void initComponents() {
        jButton1 = new JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(700, 400));

        jButton1.setText("btn");

        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(305, 305, 305)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(319, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,layout.createSequentialGroup()
              .addContainerGap(228, Short.MAX_VALUE)
              .addComponent(jButton1)
              .addGap(217, 217, 217))
        );

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/bbb/btn.png"));
        jButton1.setIcon(icon);

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new NewFrame().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private JButton jButton1; 
}
```

Alguns detalhes:

- A classe NewFrame já é a principal;
- Já coloquei uma pasta com o mesmo nome do pacote, no mesmo diretório, com as mesmas imagens;
- Se eu deixar o botão sem nenhum ícone, o .jar abre normalmente;
- O programa abre normalmente no NetBeans (com ou sem ícone);
- Também já tentei abrir pelo cmd(sem sucesso);
- O .jar não abre a janela(JFrame), mas aparece aberto em segundo plano no Gerenciador de Tarefas.
  [image: Ger. de Tar. após tentar abrir o .jar 3x]

Por favor, me ajudem. Não sei mais o que fazer ;-; .

Comment: Nesse seu projeto no NetBeans, a única classe com um método `main` é essa? Se você abrir o seu .jar, haverá um arquivo `META-INF\MANIFEST.MF`, veja se a propriedade `Main-Class:` está apontando para `bbb.NewFrame`.

Comment: O problema pra mim parece ser referencia nula.Provavelmente essa `/bbb/btn.png` não está sendo adicionada ao jar, e se executar fora do netbeans, o java não consegue localizar.

Comment: Faça o seguinte teste: Execute o jar com o seguinte no prompt de comando com o seguinte comando: `java -jar <caminho completo da pasta>\<nomedojar>.jar`. Veja se estoura erro, se sim, copie a stacktrace e adicione na pergunta.